# Fetch records only for today's date by using PHP & Mysql

Tags: mysql, php

I have a column in my table as date and time format like YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
And i want to fetch data which was stored on current date only, everyday I'll be getting data for 24hrs only,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `DATE()` function:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
 WHERE DATE(col1) = DATE(NOW()) -- date parts are equal (HH:MM:SS are dropped)
 ORDER BY col1 ASC
;
```

Keep in mind that such condition can't be covered by index and can be slow/very slow on a big tables. If the query performance is inappropriate you have to store the date and time parts separately. Columns of types DATE and TIME can be indexed by single multicolumn index.

Comment: Thanks #Kondybas bro! i got an idea! and its working fine now!

Comment: `DATE(NOW())` can be simplified to `CURDATE()`.

Comment: @RickJames Also as of v8 `mysql` allows the functional indexes so this query can be as fast as any other indexed one.

Comment: @Kondybas - Good.  (But I would not want to advocate `INDEX(DATE(col))`, especially if `INDEX(col)` were also needed.)